# Cannot implicitly convert type 'AppName.MyListItem' to 'AppName.MySecundPage.MyListItem'?

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, tabbedpage

I have a `TabbedPage` and what I intend to do, is to stream a json `ListView` into a `ContentPage` that is under the MainPage.

As far I can understand, the lost comes to place when translating to the xaml.

Can anyone help me out with this?

My code looks like this:

My C# file

```cs
void OnListViewItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs eventInfo)
{
    if (eventInfo.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        cityItem clickedCityName = (cityItem)eventInfo.SelectedItem;

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(clickedCityName.cityAddress);
        citiesListView.SelectedItem = null;

        SingelCityPage pcity = new SingelCityPage ();
        pcity.currentCity = clickedCityName;

        //Looks like I am missing something here but I don't find any reference.
        //or is in the XML that its missing the connection? 
        Navigation.PushAsync(pcity);
        }
    }
```

My Xaml

```xml
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="citiesListView">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                          <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                                <AbsoluteLayout Padding="10,10,10,10">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding cityName}" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.0, 0.0, 0.75, 0.5" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" />
                                    <Label Text="{Binding cityLocation}" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.0, 1.0, 0.75, 0.5" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" />
                                    <Label Text="{Binding cityAdress}" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1.0, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" />
                                </AbsoluteLayout>
                          </ViewCell.ContextActions>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView> 
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: Where do you get this error? I can't see anywhere you use the type mentioned in the title. It doesn't seem you have posted the _relevant_ code for this.

Answer (score 0):

In your code base, you have (at least) 2 classes named `MyListItem` in different namespaces. One might be autogenerated by json deserialization, I can only guess here.

Even if they have the same name, they are different classes, and an instance of one can not be converted to an instance of the other.

Make sure you use the same type everywhere.

Guessing again, because the pasted snippets aren't helpful, I'd say the issue happens on this line:

```cs
pcity.currentCity = clickedCityName;
```